JSON progress bar always full in SharePoint
Is there any way to show a progress bar under a text formatted as Accountability in SharePoint online?
The progress bar must put in relation 2 values: let's call the first Amount Financed and the second Amount Received. The bar should progress when Amount Received increases in relation to Amount Financed. I tried with this code but the progress bar is always full.
Thank you.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "8px",
        "white-space": "nowrap"
      }
    }
  ],
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-field-dataBars"
  },
  "style": {
    "padding": "0",
    "width": "=if(@currentField >= [$AmountFinanced], '100%', (@currentField * 5) + '%')"
  }
}


On which column you applied this JSON formatting code? Are both Amount column of type "Number"? If not, what is the column type for these columns?

Check these 2 JSON samples and let me know if it works for you: Data Bar and Multi-Colored Databars.
